# Is it possible to Restrict Image size and upload only of certain size

Tags: java, file-handling

I am uploading file using the above code, the code works fine .

My question is, is it possible to restrict image to 75 kb only during image upload ??

In case it exceeds 75 kb, I dont want to throw an `exception`, but continue upload with what I got

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a web project? If Yes Which Framework you are using?

Comment: Have you considered summing `read` into a counter and exit the while loop when the bytes count is greater than 75k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final static int MAX_SIZE = 75000;

private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        int size = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while (size < MAX_SIZE && (read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            size += read;
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are various way to do it . if you are Using **Struts** then Edit `Strtus.xml`and Use where value Denotes File Size limit

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="30000000" />
```

**Servlet**

```
@MultipartConfig(
location="/tmp", 
fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024,    // 1 MB
maxFileSize=1024*1024*5,        // 5 MB 
maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5    // 25 MB
)
```

or

```
<max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
```

**Java**

```
final static int MAX_SIZE = 50000;//Max Limit of File
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to calculate file size in kb.

```
 long fileSize = file.length()/1024;
 System.out.println("fileSize="+fileSize);
 if(fileSize==75){

  }else{

    }
```